# How can I mirror edit actions in multiple buffers in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have two buffers open side by side in Emacs. As I delete (or modify) lines in the first file, I would like the second file to receive the same commands / cursor position. Is this possible?

Comment: I could always use macros but I prefer them to be simultaneous (unless I'm reading that wrong).

Comment: sdasdadas: Assuming your comment is a response to wvxvw, I'm not sure how macros are relevant? `command-log-mode` has the functionality for intercepting and recording commands for subsequent playback. You could therefore adapt that code to instead play back each command immediately in the second buffer. I believe that is what wvxvw was getting at.

Comment: Here's a not-identical but very similar question with some possibly useful code to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987071/mirroring-location-in-file-in-two-opened-buffers-side-by-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I know of to what you've described is the [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/emacsmirror/multiple-cursors) package, which is pretty cool, but it only implements multiple cursors within a single buffer.  So I suppose that you could:

1. Append one of the buffer contents to the other;
2. Spawn multiple cursors using the package I mentioned;
3. Split the windows;
4. Edit away;
5. Move the appended buffer contents back to its original location.

With what I suspect would be a considerable amount of hacking, one might be able to extend `multiple-cursors` to handle multiple buffers, but I think this would be opening up a huge can of worms.  What if the two buffers are in different modes, and you enter a key sequence that's bound to different commands that do vastly different things?

Comment: I believe this to be my best choice - if it works out I'll come back and append the question and accept this answer. Thank you.